# SWI-Prolog depth-first search?

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

My aim is to develop a simple program to run a game called 'Kayles' which is similar to Skittles. You have a row of bottles, 2 players knock them down in turns, and the player to knock the last bottle(s) down wins. You can knock 1 or 2 bottles down only, and they have to be next to each other.

The first part of this program was to decide how to represent a bottle, and an empty space. I have decided to use a list, where 1 represents a bottle and 0 represents an empty space.

The second part of this program was to print the current state to the terminal where a bottle is represented by an asterisk * and an empty space is represented by a gap.

The third part of this program was to list and print all the possible next states reachable from a current state. For example, if you have 3 bottles [1,1,1], one possible next state is [0,1,1] as the first bottle was knocked down. So this predicate is supposed to print a list of all possible next states, again represented by * and space.

I have successfully done the above, and this is my code so far:

```
printstate([]) :- nl.
printstate([B|L]) :- (B=0 -> write(' '); write('*')), printstate(L).

next([1|S], [0|S]).
next([1,1|S], [0,0|S]).
next([0|S], [0|T]) :- next(S,T).
next([1|S], [1|T]) :- next(S,T).

printnextstates(S,T) :- next(S,T), printstate(T), fail.
```

The next bit is the bit I am stuck on! So the aim is to define the value of a state to be 1 if the first player to move can force a win, and 0 otherwise. I am to write a predicate value(S,X) which will compute the value X of any game state S by a depth-first search through the game tree. I should use assert if possible to avoid the search exploring any position more than once.

I have no idea how to do this!

So far this is what I can come up with:

```
value(S,X) :- S = 1, ([S,T] = 1); 0.
```

But I'm sure it's not that simple, yet I have no idea how to begin this question! I've researched depth-first search but I don't really understand it enough to write this... does anyone have any idea how one may go about in starting this question?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since a player is free to pick elements at any position, a remarkable simplification results from an appropriate data representation of the problem: let's say that we keep a list of available bottles. Then you could do just declaring the logic:

```
win(P) :-
    move(P, P1),
    \+ win(P1).
win(P) :- move(P, []).

move([_|R], R).
move([_,_|R], R).
```

Here a dumb test, up to some arbitrary length, without noting that a simple recurrence formula gives the result

```
?- setof(N, L^(between(1,20,N),length(L,N),win(L)), Wins).
Wins = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13|...].
```

Comment: What is the list of wins? I'm representing a bottle as 1 and empty space as 0, a winning state as 1 and 0 otherwise?

Comment: Wins are the number of 1s that lead, well, to a sure win. A possibility to build the list to give to win/1 is `include(=(1),YourState,ToWin)`

Comment: Is there a way to do this using depth-first search? I don't understand your code :( A predicate, value(S,X), is supposed to compute the value X of any game state S by a depth-first search through the game tree and should define the value of a state to be 1 if the firstp layer to move can force a win and 0 otherwise?

Comment: depth first search is the only mean Prolog use to perform a search. Thus win/1 *does* a depth first search. The trick it's the search space representation. I used 1 list exactly to avoid any 'distraction' that would arise from counting bottles...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand    include(=(1),YourState,ToWin) - can you please explain it to me??

Comment: yes: [include](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3)/3 keep any element from a list (2° argument) that satisfy a predicate (the 1° argument). That predicate here is equality to 1. The second predicate argument come from the list.

Comment: But what do I actually replace YourState and ToWin with? I've tried replacing YourState with next(S,T) and [S|T] but it's asking me to define them too. I've placed include after the win predicate:   
    win(P) :-    move(P, P1), \+ win(P1), include(=(1),YourState,ToWin).

Comment: YourState is a list of 0 or 1. You pass that to include/3, and get a list to pass to win/1

Comment: @CapelliC: I think your `move` should take into account that you can only knock down two bottles if they are adjacent as in, there is not only no other bottle between them but also no hole. e.g. `move([3,5],[]).` should be false.

Comment: @MikeHartl:  Also CapelliC's logic for `move/2` only permits knocking down one or two bottles at the beginning of the list.  Presumably an important part of the strategy involves creating "holes" in the original line-up.  The logic for `win/1` seems impeccable.